# Effective SpriteBatching in XNA?

Tags: xna, 2d, textures, efficiency, spritebatch

What is an example of efficient sprite batching in XNA?

I don't know when (if ever) I would do something like this:

```
spriteBatch.Begin()
DrawSprite1();
spriteBatch.End();

spriteBatch.Begin();
DrawSprite2();
spriteBatch.End();
```

Is there any time within a draw method that I would separate drawing calls like this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Effective usage is only using one single `spritebatch` for the game. Simply call `Begin()` at the start of the frame and `End()` at the end.

However, there are some usage for multiple batches. You can set them up only draw the content when you call `End()`. With this you could use one `spritebatch` for the game and one for the GUI with having problem with game elements overlapping GUI elements.
[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20151001205903/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2006/12/14/spritebatch-sorting-part-2.aspx)

Comment: Another use for multiple spritebatch, is for when you want to draw certain objects with a different transformation matrix, or other types of spritebatch manipulations.